# How to load 3D numpy array as dataframe in seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data in a CSV file, for example

```
0, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2
2, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3
3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 1
```

I load it using `np.genfromtxt, then reshape it into a 3D array of shape (3,2,3), then sum it on axis 1.

I want to load it as a dataframe into Seaborn to plot it, what is the most pythonic way of doing it ?

Example:

```
values = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')    # len(values) evaluates
values = np.reshape(values,(3,2,len(values)))        # to 3 in that case      
sum_rates = np.sum(values,axis=1)
sns.lineplot(values)
```

I also would like to get it to display the average, the median and the quartiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```
import pandas as pd

filname = r'path/to/file'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
print df
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  3  4  2  4  2
1  2  1  7  2  8  3
2  3  4  6  2  5  1

# to get sum
sum = df.sum(axis=1)
print sum
0    15
1    23
2    21

# to plot data
df.plot()
```

[image]

```
# to get count, mean, std ...
print df.describe()
              0         1         2    3         4    5
count  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000  3.0  3.000000  3.0
mean   1.666667  2.666667  5.666667  2.0  5.666667  2.0
std    1.527525  1.527525  1.527525  0.0  2.081666  1.0
min    0.000000  1.000000  4.000000  2.0  4.000000  1.0
25%    1.000000  2.000000  5.000000  2.0  4.500000  1.5
50%    2.000000  3.000000  6.000000  2.0  5.000000  2.0
75%    2.500000  3.500000  6.500000  2.0  6.500000  2.5
max    3.000000  4.000000  7.000000  2.0  8.000000  3.0
```

Comment: The issue with your answer is that the data is loaded as 2D, not 3D. I want to sum over each non-overlapping pair of each line here for example.